# Jave - method is - parseByte(String s, int radix) - I can't understand it

Tags: java

This is an example the tutorial gives me. I cannot understand the answer - Parse byte value of 123 is 83 Parse byte value of -1a is -26. Please try to explain the method to me in a very simple way.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class ByteDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create 2 byte primitives bt1, bt2
      byte bt1, bt2;

      // create and assign values to String's s1, s2
      String s1 = "123";
      String s2 = "-1a";

      // create and assign values to int r1, r2
      int r1 = 8;  // represents octal
      int r2 = 16; // represents hexadecimal

      /**
       *  static method is called using class name. Assign parseByte
       *  result on s1, s2 to bt1, bt2 using radix r1, r2
       */
      bt1 = Byte.parseByte(s1, r1);
      bt2 = Byte.parseByte(s2, r2);

      String str1 = "Parse byte value of " + s1 + " is " + bt1;
      String str2 = "Parse byte value of " + s2 + " is " + bt2;

      // print bt1, bt2 values
      System.out.println( str1 );
      System.out.println( str2 );
   }
}
```

Comment: doc perhaps help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte-java.lang.String-int-

Answer (score 2):

The first value, 123, is interpreted as an octal number, i.e. a number with base 8.

Now 1 * 8^2 + 2 * 8 + 3 = 64 + 16 + 3 = 83

The second value, -1a, is interpreted as a hexadecimal number, i.e. a number with base 16. Due to the fact that we only have 10 symbols for digits (0, .., 9), the symbols a,b,c,d,e,f are used to represent digits with a decimal value larger than 9. So a(16) = 10(10), b(16) = 11(10) and so on.

And - (1 * 16 + 10) = -26

Answer (score 2):

In your first example you take 123 and interpret it as a number in octal representation, that means the first digit is not 100 but only 64 (8*8). So 123 is interpreted as 8*8*1+8*2+3 = 83.
In the second example 1a is interpreted as in hexadecimal representation. So -1a = -(16*1+10) = -26.